# Fastest way to extract n bytes from uint8_t buffer

Tags: performance, c

I work a lot with byte buffers and have to extract different parts. In this example, it's 4 byte, but it ranges from a single bit to 128 bit. Speed is the most important metric here. See the code for a MWE. I'd like to know if there is a better way.

```
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t get_data(uint8_t *buf, size_t off)
{
    return ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 0]) << 24) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 1]) << 16) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 2])  <<  8) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 3]));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint8_t buf[128];

    /* get some example data */
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
        buf[i] = i;

    /* we want the data from offset 10 as an uint32_t */
    uint32_t res = get_data(buf, 10);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean bit or byte at the end?

Comment: I used both bit and byte in my question intentionally, although I usually work with bytes. But in rare cases I also need to know the value of individual bits, hence the range 1 to 128.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want low level operations, I'd suggest `memmove`

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static uint32_t get_data(uint8_t *buf, size_t off)
{
    return ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 0]) << 24) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 1]) << 16) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 2])  <<  8) +
                  ((uint32_t)(buf[off + 3]));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint8_t buf[128];

    /* get some example data */
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
        buf[i] = i;

    clock_t t = clock();
    uint32_t res;
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        memmove(&res, buf+10, sizeof(uint32_t));
    t = clock() -t;
    printf("Time %lf\n", (double)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    t = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
     res = get_data(buf, 10);
    t = clock() -t;
    printf("Time %lf\n", (double)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Because a single copy doesn't show any difference I tried with 10.000 and my results were:

```
Time 0.000049
Time 0.000090
```

Almost double the speedup

- EDIT 1: As mentioned in the comments, memcpy is a viable alternative
  to memmove.
- EDIT 2: The speed difference in this example cannot be
  observed with -O flag as the compiler executes the loop only one
  time.

Comment: Might want to compare with `memcpy`, as the buffers don't overlap.

Comment: Tried this with clang, from -O0 to -O3. I see absolutly no difference from manual bit shifting to memmove/memcpy. Anyway, as it is not slower, memcpy is much shorter to write and better readable.

Comment: I think it's because -O3 understands the silly for loop and executes it only one time so as I wrote, with one copy you can't tell the difference. With 1billion in the for loop it takes 4 seconds without -O and 0.00001 sec with so I guess that's it

Comment: There is a difference between the OP's code and `memmove`/`memcpy`: The result with the latter depends on the system's byte order, whereas OP's result doesn't.

Comment: `memmove` to a `uint32_t` simply gets optimized away to `mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+rsi]` on GCC 7.2 (-O3)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if there is a better way.

`uint32_t res = get_data(buf, 10);` and `get_data(buf, 10)` are a good first step as 1) it is functionally correct and 2) highly portable.

Any "better" solution should use this as the baseline in which to compare/profile.

The next performance step involves some assumptions.  **If** the `uint32_t` is of the expected endian, than a simple`memcpy()` will work in lieu of `get_data()`.

```
memcpy(&res, buf + 10, sizeof ref);
```

Although this may look like a function call, a worthy compiler "understands" `memcpy()` and can replace this with efficient in-line emitted code. Let your good compiler do its job - or get a better compiler.

If code "knows" `res and`ref`do not overflow`memcpy()`is faster, or as fast as memmove()`.  IAC, a good compiler replaces either of these with in-line code for such small `sizeof ref` copies. [mox nix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mox_nix)

---

[Soapbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox): Overall, the core issue with modern code efficiency improvement is that it is unlikely to be a good investment of coding expense/effort.  Spend time writing good code without employing tricks.  Real efficiency  improvement comes from higher level choices than this - which can vary from implementation to implementation.  You may code something faster on a select platform, but be slower on the next as the [big O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is the same,